# GIT Created new branch C after pushing branch B

Tags: git, branch, push

I have a `master` branch. I have created a branch `B`, pushed Branch `B` with the required changes to the repository. 
Changes haven't been merged by my peer yet.

Meanwhile, i need to work on a different task and i did

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b C
```

when i run `git branch --contains`, i can see

```
* C
master
B
```

why am i seeing B branch? I thought i will see B if i create a new branch from B i.e.,

```
git checkout B
git checkout -b C
```

if an earlier branch is not merged yet and if i want to work on a new task with a new branch, what is the best way to avoid unwanted branch changes in the new branch

i had a problem few days ago where a pushed branch changes seem to appear in my new branch and i had to resolve by copying the required changes again to a new branch.

Thanks.

Comment: you seem not to know how branching works in git... please invest sometime reading the [git docs here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell)

Comment: Branch B still exists in the repository, and you can switch to it. It will continue to exist until it is merged with master (and master contains all of the changes that B does). Your branch C is forked from master at an earlier time, but as long as you don't make any conflicting changes with B, when it is merged with master you can fast-forward any changes into C if you like.

Comment: Thanks. The document and the answers helped me understand the branching basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs for `git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

> With `--contains`, shows only the branches that contain the named commit (in other words, the branches whose tip commits are descendants of the named commit) … If the  argument is missing it defaults to *HEAD* (i.e. the tip of the current branch)

This command shows branches that contain the given commit. Since you didn't provide one, you're seeing commits that contain the tip of branch `C`.

Since you haven't committed anything new to branch `C`, the commit at the tip of branch `C` is included in branch `B` (and in fact it's the same commit at the tip of branch `B`).

Answer (score 0):

It shows branch B because that branch is ahead of master, you created C from master, thus your HEAD commit (used if commit is unspecified) is inside branch B.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

> --contains [] Only list branches which contain the specified commit (HEAD if not specified). Implies --list.